Geometry Optimization and Symmetry (Quantum ESPRESSO)
Before asking anything, I'd like to clarify that I'm an almost a beginner in using Quantum ESPRESSO, so my question may be trivial for an advanced user.
I'd like to perform a vc-relax calculation on a TiO2 (rutile) crystal. The input of the geometrical optimization recognizes correctly the starting geometry and its space group (136).
After this step, I performed a new scf calculation, using optimized lattice parameters and atomic position in the input file but the system recognizes a new space group symmetry.
I think there should be a way to optimize the cell with the constraints of keeping the initial symmetry.
I've already tried to set cell_dofree = 'ibrav', but obviously to the same bravais lattice there may be several space groups.
Thank you in advance for your help!
This is the input when I used "space_group" + "crystal_sg" options:
&CONTROL
    calculation   = "vc-relax"
    forc_conv_thr =  1.00000e-08
    nstep         = 200
    pseudo_dir    = "./pseudo"
/

&SYSTEM
    celldm(1)                 =  4.59420e+00
    celldm(2)                 =  4.59420e+00
    celldm(3)                 =  2.95940e+00
    space_group               = 136
    degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   =  2.25000e+02
    ecutwfc                   =  2.50000e+01
    ibrav                     = 6
    nat                       = 2
    ntyp                      = 2
    occupations               = "smearing"
    smearing                  = "cold"
/

&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-06
    electron_maxstep = 200
    mixing_beta      =  4.00000e-01
    startingpot      = "atomic"
    startingwfc      = "atomic+random"
/

&IONS
    ion_dynamics = "bfgs"
/

&CELL
    cell_dofree    = "ibrav"
    cell_dynamics  = "bfgs"
    press          =  0.00000e+00
    press_conv_thr =  5.00000e-01
/

K_POINTS {automatic}
 7 7 11 0 0 0

ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ti   47.86700  Ti.upf
O    15.99940  O.upf

ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal_sg}
Ti 0      0      0
O  0.3045 0.3045 0


Hello & welcome to MMSE! If I understand correctly, you want to find the optimized lattice parameters (a and c) but do not want to change the space group. In this case, instead of a vc-relax calculation where the code chooses how to move the atomic positions, or how to change the lattice parameter along the optimization, you can consider multiple scf calculations by changing a and c manually. Then you can plot the total energy against a and c (a contour plot or a 3D plot). The set of values which gives you the minimum energy is the values you are looking for.

Ok, I got what you told me! How can I scale the lattice parameters, I mean, which steps do I have to apply? After I found the minimum, and chosen the lattice parameter, do I have to optimize also the atomic positions (keep the parameters unchanged)?
By the way, thank you for your answer and free palestine always!

Try 'ibrav+2Dxz' if works.

@Pranavkumar unfortunately it doesn't work! Thank you anyhow!

@MartinoNapoli Yes, after finding the optimized lattice parameters, you can then relax the atomic positions only (calculation='relax'), not vc-relax. About the scaling of the lattice parameter, you can directly use a/celldm(1) and c/celldm(3) if you are not using ibrav=0 (be careful about the unit). If you are using ibrav=0 then it depends how you defined your input file. Could you add your input file to the post as an edit? Then I, or somebody else, can write an answer detailing the steps.

Is 'ibrav+2Dxz' command didn't work or it didn't preserve same space group. Can we look into your input and output files as well.

It didn't preserved symmetry, but I realized that setting space_group in the system card and giving the coordinates of atoms in crystal_sg does!

I edited the main question adding 'crystal_sg' option, now the only thing I have to understand is If I have to use strictly primitive cell parameters in the input or conventional cell unit is a consistent choice too
Of course I'm referring to other structures since the "rutile" has a primitive conventional cell!
